# why does adding "-Wl,-static -lmy_static_lib" clobber the library search path?

Tags: linux, gcc

I have a build that uses several .so libraries to link. I now want to add a static library to the application so I appended (at the end of the command line compiler options) the following to the g++ compile line:

```
-Wl,-static -lmy_static_lib
```

This breaks my build with the following error:

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

I have tried several things like rearranging the -l libraries, putting the static options at the first, last, giving a -L for the path to the libgcc_s.so, etc.

Anybody have a suggestion on how to add that static library to my build without breaking the existing build?  BTW: this is on Ubuntu 16.04, g++ version 5.4.0

Thanks,
-Andres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command instructs the compiler to pass "-static" to the linker - which means to create a static executable. What you probably were looking for is `-Wl,-Bstatic` which means to select the static version of the libraries following after this statement. Note that this is only needed when there are both versions (static and shared) available. If your library only has a static version of the library that one would be chosen without needing the `-Wl,-Bstatic` statement.